# RandomVariate and Map, strange behavior noticed

Tags: random, map

I'm performing Bayesian Analysis and I have written this piece of code

```
successes = 6; trials = 16;
samples = 20000;
(*prior = BinomialDistribution[trials, 0.333];*)
prior = UniformDistribution[{0, 1}];
priorsamples = RandomVariate[prior, samples];
model[theta_] := BinomialDistribution[trials, theta];
delta = 0.05;
bins = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, delta}];
priorbin = BinCounts[priorsamples, {bins}];
generated = {priorsamples, 
    RandomVariate[#] & /@ (model[#] & /@ priorsamples)}\[Transpose];
posteriorsamples = (Select[
      generated, #[[2]] == successes &]\[Transpose])[[1]];
posteriorbins = BinCounts[posteriorsamples, {bins}];
Show[
 Plot[-1, {x, 0, 1}],
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[{Opacity[0.5], Red}], 
   Rectangle[{#[[1]], 
       0}, {#[[1]] + delta, #[[2]]/samples/
        delta}] & /@ ({bins[[1 ;; -2]], priorbin}\[Transpose])}],
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[{Opacity[0.5], Blue}], 
   Rectangle[{#[[1]], 
       0}, {#[[1]] + delta, #[[2]]/Length[posteriorsamples]/
        delta}] & /@ ({bins[[1 ;; -2]], 
       posteriorbins}\[Transpose])}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 5}}
 ]
```

using UniformDistribution I have no problem. Using BinomialDistribution (uncomment the corresponding line) I got the following error

[image]

that should occur when Mathematica computes `generated` by processing RandomVariate and Map. I'm runnning version 10.3 under Ubuntu 16.04. Could you reproduce this error?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, I reproduce the error. Is it so strange? If `prior = BinomialDistribution[trials, 0.333]` then sampling from `prior` will certainly give integers, and almost certainly some larger than 1. You then feed these samples back to `model` as the _probabilities_ `p` for a single "success" in a binomial sampling. Is this really intended? It does not make sense to me.

Comment: you're right. I did not mean to do that, I meant feeding a beta! Now I see.